# Factory methods in objective c

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, ios6, xml-parsing

I am parsing an xml feed (with a NSXML parser) where I need to create a bunch of the same object, foo, and then add these objects to a NSMutableArray.  My question concerns memory management while I attempt this.

As I see it, my two options are:
1) Create a factory method that creates the objects as I need them.  This is my factory method, which I've added as a method in the xml parser.

```
+ (id)create_foo
{
return [[foo alloc] init];
}
```

2) I have automatic reference counting on.  So I was thinking that I could create a single foo object as an instance variable in the xml parser and let the auto memory management take care of releasing the object when I need to create a new foo object. So in the didStartelement method of the NSXML parser

```
if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"new_foo"])
{
    current_foo = [foo alloc];
}
```

Which is more efficient?  The second option seems like less work, but I'm worried about the auto reference counting.  Is there a third option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have a measurable performance bottleneck that you have identified?

If not, don't worry about it.

And if you use ARC, the compiler/runtime will optimize away the use of autorelease wherever possible (which includes factory methods).

Comment: I am getting 'Developer Tools' and will get back to you on whether or not I see a bottleneck.  I am interested as to the performance of ARC.  I am curious - Do most professional developers use ARC or do they like to handle memory management themselves?

Comment: Depends on the team; some do, some don't.  I've been developing Objective-C since 1989 and use ARC on all projects I'm involved in these days (including ones at Apple).  ARC's performance is faster than manual retain release in many cases, and on par in others.